# How can I simulate a CALL instruction by using JMP?

Tags: function, assembly, x86

Like this but without the `CALL` instruction. I suppose that I should use `JMP` and probably other instructions.

```
PUSH 5
PUSH 4
CALL Function
```

Comment: read the manual where it describes what a call does, then create a list of instructions that do the same thing ending with a jump which is the last thing a call does.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is fairly easy to do.  Push the return address onto the stack and then jump to the subroutine.
The final code looks like this:

```
   PUSH 5
   PUSH 4
   PUSH offset label1
   jmp Function
 label1: ; returns here
   leas esp, 8[esp]

 Function: 
   ...
   ret
```

*While this works, you really don't want to do this.*  On most modern processors, an on-chip call stack return address cache is kept, which pushes return addresses on a call, and pops return addresses on an RET.  Being on the processor this has extremely short update/access times, which means the RET instruction can use the call-stack cache popped value to predict where the PC should go next, rather than waiting for the actual memory read from the memory location actually pointed to by ESP.  If you do the "PUSH offset label1" trick,
this cache does not get updated, and thus the RET branch prediction is wrong and the processor pipeline gets blown, having a severe negative impact on performance.  (I think IBM has a patent on special instructions which are essentially "PUSHRETURNADDRESS k" and "POPRETURNADDESS", allowing this trick to be used on some of their CPUs.  Alas, not on the x86.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the situation. If the last thing your function does before returning is call another function, you can simply jump to that function. This is called tail call elimination, and is an optimization performed by many compilers. Example:

```
foo:
    call B
    call A
    ret
```

Tail call elimination replaces the last two lines with a single jump instruction:

```
foo:
    call B
    jmp  A
```

This works because the stack contains the return address of `foo`'s caller. So when function `A` returns, it returns back to the function that called `foo`.

It you want execution to resume after the jump to A, push that address onto the stack before jumping:

```
foo:
    call B
    push offset bar
    jmp  A
bar:
```

However, I can think of no reason why anybody would want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Before x86-64, `call` was the only instruction that could read EIP.  (I guess `int` as well, but it doesn't put the result anywhere you can read from user-space).

So it's impossible to simulate `call` in position-independent code.  In fact, 32-bit PIC code *uses* `call` to find out its own address.

But in x86-64, we have RIP-relative `lea`

```
    ... put function args in registers

    lea    rax, [rel ret_addr]    ; AT&T lea ret_addr(%rip), %rax
    push   rax
    jmp    call_target
ret_addr:
```

---

`call` itself internally decodes as `push RIP` / `jmp target`, where RIP during execution of an instruction = address of the end of that instruction = start of the next.

---

**Of course this is normally terrible for performance, unbalancing the return-address predictor stack.**  http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/04/ras-microbenchmarks/.  Use a normal `call` unless you *want* a `ret` to mispredict, e.g. for a retpoline or specpoline.

(A tailcall with *just* `jmp` is fine, collapsing a call/ret pair into a jmp, but pushing a new return address manually is always a problem.)