# What is the difference between the ret instruction in x86 and x64?

Tags: assembly, x86, return, x86-64

I was recently trying out a stack overflow exercise on x64. When performing this on x86, I would expect the following for a junk overwrite address (e.g. 'AAAA'):

1. The data I provide overflows the buffer, and overwrites the return address
2. Upon `ret`, the (overwritten) return address will be (effectively) popped into the EIP register
3. It is realised that the address is not valid, and a segmentation fault is raised

In x64, this seems different (beyond the interchange of EIP with RIP in the above steps). When providing a junk address of 'AAAAAAA', the processor seems to do some validity checking *before* popping the address. By observation, it seems required that the two most significant bytes of the address are null, before it is loaded. Otherwise, a segfault occurs. I believe this is due to the use of 48-bit addressing in x64, however I was under the impression that addresses starting with 0xFFFF were also valid, yet this also produces a segfault.

Is this an accurate description of the difference? Why is this check performed before the data is loaded into the RIP register, whilst the other validity check is performed afterwards? Are there any other differences between these instructions?

EDIT: To clarify my observations, I note that when a 8-byte return address is provided, the RIP still points to the address of the `ret` instruction, and the RSP still points to the overwritten return address on segfault. When an 6-byte return address is provided, the overwritten address has been popped into the RIP when the segfault is observed.

Comment: The check is done early because the `rip` register might not even have the bits in hardware so it can't be loaded. Yes, the top part of the address range should also be canonical, but you must use sign extension. So for example `0xffff800000000000` is canonical and will be loaded into `rip` and only fault afterwards :) `0xffff4141414141414141` is not canonical.

Comment: Addresses starting with `0xffff` are only valid in kernel mode afaik.

Comment: @fuz: They're not automatically invalid (non-canonical), they're only protected by the normal page-table mechanism.  (e.g. kernels set the U/S bit in PTEs so that most / all of those virtual pages are supervisor-only).  Linux for example maps the `ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000` range into user-space processes as the `[vsyscall]` page.  (`cat /proc/self/maps`).

Comment: @Vortix: What exactly are you claiming happens? That RSP isn't updated or something? How are you distinguishing between code-fetch from an invalid page leading to a segfault vs. attempting to load a non-canonical address into RIP? The Operation section of the manual for [`ret`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret) is complicated by clutter from `retf` (far), but IA-32E-MODE-RETURN-TO-SAME-PRIVILEGE-LEVEL: includes `IF the return instruction pointer is not within canonical address space
  THEN #GP(0); FI;`.  Instead of `#PF`, but GP or invalid pagefault both get the kernel to deliver SIGSEGV

Comment: Thanks for the information, everyone! @Jester indeed, it loads as you said!

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the reference, very interesting! I observe that the RSP points to the overwritten return address, and the RIP points to the address of the `ret` instruction when the segfault occurs, whereas when a 6-byte address is provided, the overwritten address has been popped into the RIP when the segfault is observed.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to say that more clearly.  Interesting that RSP doesn't get updated before the fault.  So it's not code-fetch from a non-canonical address that faults, it's the `ret` instruction's attempt to set RIP to a non-canonical address.  That makes the whole RET instruction fault, meaning that none of its effects are visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting that RSP doesn't get updated before the fault.  So it's not code-fetch from a non-canonical address that faults, it's the `ret` instruction's attempt to set RIP to a non-canonical address.

That makes the whole RET instruction fault, meaning that none of its effects are visible.  (Because [Intel's manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret) doesn't define any partial-progress / stuff updated even on fault behaviour for `ret`.)

Unfortunately the Operation section for `ret` in Intel's manual is a rats nest of conditionals because they use one block to document near and far, and every combination of mode and operand-size.  Plain `ret` in 64-bit mode is "IA-32e mode", operand-size=64, and "near" (not changing CS to a different code segment, just changing RIP).

In that case, x86-64 **normal `ret` is basically `pop rip`**.
32-bit mode normal `ret` is basically `pop eip`.
Nothing more, nothing less.  `RIP = *RSP++`.

See also

- [Does it matter where the ret instruction is called in a procedure in x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714626/does-it-matter-where-the-ret-instruction-is-called-in-a-procedure-in-x86-assembl)
- [What is the x86 "ret" instruction equivalent to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129107/what-is-the-x86-ret-instruction-equivalent-to/54816685#54816685)
- [How can I simulate a CALL instruction by using JMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248227/how-can-i-simulate-a-call-instruction-by-using-jmp/55733716#55733716)

---

Note that the upper-half of the canonical range starts at `0xffff800000000000`: 48 bits *sign extended* to 64.  `0xffff7f0000000000` is not canonical.  The upper 16 have to match bit 48.

Generally, x86-64 seems to be designed so RIP can truly be only as wide as the virtual address width, 48 or 57 bits, never needing to hold a non-canonical address.  Any attempt to set RIP to a non-canonical value faults on the attempt, not later on code fetch.