# RIP register size

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, exploit

I've been studying binary exploitation and recently I found a problem that I cannot find an answer for...
I have the following code:

```
void vuln(char *s) {
   char buf[10];
   strcpy(buf, s);
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
   vuln(argv[1]);
   printf("YOU LOSE!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

The strcpy call allows me to exploit a buffer overflow so I can override the RBP and RIP registers... the thing is send 10 'A' to fill the buffer, 8 'B' to fill the RBP and only 6 'C' to fill the RIP?! I cannot understand why only 6 bytes are needed instead of 8, which is the register size (64bit platform)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a duplicate of [Why do x86-64 systems have only a 48 bit virtual address space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716946/why-do-x86-64-systems-have-only-a-48-bit-virtual-address-space), but the saved/future RIP (return address) *is* 64-bit, you just don't need to write the two high zeros.  You can only write one anyway, as the terminating zero byte for the C string.

x86-64 only uses 48 of the 64 bits, and user-space is the low half of the 48-bit "canonical" range of virtual address space.  So the top 2 bytes of a return address are already zero.  See [Why in x86-64 the virtual address are 4 bits shorter than physical (48 bits vs. 52 long)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46509152)  and related: [What is the difference between the ret instruction in x86 and x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62364368)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even know how to search for this...