# Why am I getting a segmentation fault when moving the stack pointer?

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, att, stack-pointer

Working with assembly code and wondering why I get a seg fault with the instruction subl $8, %esp?

```
        pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp

        movl 16(%ebp), %esi
        movl 12(%ebp), %edi
        movl 8(%ebp), %eax
        movl $0, %ebx
        subl $8, %esp
        jmp .LL1

.LL1:
        cmpl %ebx, %esi
        je .LL2
        movl %ebx, 4(%esp)
        movl %eax, (%esp)
        addl $1, %ebx
        jmp .LL1

.LL2:
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

segfault on subl $8, %esp

Comment: Also [Does it matter where the ret instruction is called in a procedure in x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46714626) for a version not using an EBP/RBP frame pointer.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure that the code segfaults on `subl $8, %esp`?

In your code, you subtract 8 from the stack pointer, but never restore the value. The address to return to is no longer the most recent thing on the stack when you execute `ret`.

The instruction

```
movl %esp, %ebp
```

copies the original value of `%esp` to `%ebp`. When you return, you restore the original of `%ebp` with `popl`, but never restore `%esp`, so you return to some garbage address.

Before the line

```
popl %ebp
```

add

```
movl %ebp, %esp
```

to correct the stack pointer before returning.

Comment: wonderful suggestion, I updated the stack pointer in LL2 thank you kindly

Comment: @AYCHSTACKS If an answer solved your problem, you're able to mark is as the accepted answer for your question. I don't mean to pressure you to accept mine, just making sure that you know that you can do that.

Comment: @AYCHSTACKS Specifically if you don't know how to accept as an answer or would like info on how to accept an answer (and why) you can find useful information here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271768