# segmentation fault after linking c++ file with asm file

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, stack-pointer

still me. I am following the sample code given in a book but I got a segmentation fault error when linking extern asm file with cpp file

Could someone tell me what the issue is:

```
global _integer_add
; section .text i ran the code with and without "section .text" 
_integer_add:
        ; the parameters are passed  like this
        ; rdi, rsi, rdx, r8, r9
        ; a  ,  b ,  c , d
        ; I think i need to align rsp to 16 multiple
        sub rsp, 8
        ; mov a into rax
        mov rax, rdi
        ; sum a and b together
        add rax, rsi
        ; subtract from this sum c
        sub rax, rdx
        ; sum d to this quantity 
        add rax, r8
        ret
```

this is the assembly file. I tried to run both with and without the instruction sub rsp, 8. (technically I found this written in the form sub 8, rsp in a github repo, tried that too without any luck). Maybe I am getting wrong the mov add instruction. But i found this thanks to a previous question

> before call
>   the stack pointer must be aligned by a multiple of 16 bytes after call pushes the return value to the stack.
>
> This often fails by default without explicitly changing %rsp because call will store the 8 byte return address on the stack, so you usually need to do:

```
sub 8, rsp
call f
```

> often this results in a segmentation fault.
> In case you need this too

```
extern "C" int integer_add(int a, int b, int c, int d);
```

## solution

I actually found the problem. int is 32 bit so it worked using 32 bit registers  (I also left out all the rsp register business):

```
_integer_add
        mov eax, edi
        add eax, esi
        sub eax, edx
        add eax, r8d
        ret
```

just in case someone else makes a rookie mistake as I did :)

Comment: `sub rsp, 8` - okay, but now your stack pointer is misaligned relative to the return address on stack, so `ret` jumps to who-knows-where.

Comment: could you give a full answer. I would like to understand this.

Comment: On entry `rsp` points to the return address pushed on stack by the `call` that got us here, so `rsp` needs to be rewound back to that same address before the `ret` call - otherwise it will use whatever `rsp` happens to point to as its return address. --- Aside: IIRC, stack alignment only matters if your function makes calls to other functions.

Comment: ok, thank you very much for your explanation :)

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [Why am I getting a segmentation fault when moving the stack pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57224646), but that question is 32-bit code, and more importantly was also setting up EBP as a frame pointer, so the answer suggests restoring ESP by copying from EBP, rather than an add to undo it.