# Assembly Segmentation Fault Ret

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64, att

I'm writing a program that calls a subroutine factorial, which then calculates the factorial of 5. After it's returned the answer will be printed. However after I try to run my program I get a segmentation error. The debugger shows me that the error comes from line 41, a line that merely contains the Ret statement to return from the subroutine. What causes this segmentation fault?

Here's the code:

```
 1 
 2 .data
 3 .text
 4 
 5 .global main
 6 main:
 7 pushq %rbp        #prologue
 8 mov %rsp, %rbp
 9 
10 push $5               #push value on stack for it to be operated
11 call factorial
12 mov -4(%rbp), %rdi    #move answer into %rdi
13 mov $0, %rax          #no vectors
14 call printf
15 
16 mov %rbp, %rsp    #epilogue
17 popq %rbp
18 
19 mov $0, %rdi      #exit of the program
20 call exit
21 
22 factorial:
23 pushq %rbp      #epilogue
24 mov %rsp, %rbp
25 
26 mov 8(%rbp), %rdi     #move value from line 10 into %rdi
27 mov $1, %rax          # move 1 into %rax, here the result will come
28 
29 factorial_loop_start:
30 cmpb $1, (%rdi)       #compare %rdi to 1 to see if loop ends
31 je factorial_end
32 imul %rdi, %rax       #multiply %rdi with %rax and put the answer in %rax
33 dec %rdi              #decrement %rdi and return to start of loop
34 jmp factorial_loop_start
35 
36 factorial_end:
37 mov %rax, 8(%rbp)     #move the result in %rax to the original stack position of
38                       #the value that needs to be processed
39 mov %rbp, %rsp      #epilogue
40 popq %rbp
41 ret
```

Comment: Single step in the debugger and verify each instruction has the intended effect; keep track of the stack, and what is pushed onto it as well.  `call` will push a return address, so immediately after the call instruction, there should be a pointer to line 12 on the top of the stack; note the `rsp` value as well.  That same `rsp` value should be there when `ret` executes, with that same line 12 code pointer as the top item on the stack.  Start first with a small test, like `factorial(1)` and make sure it works, then work into the looping with `factorial(2)`, for example.

Comment: You're using `cmpb` to test for the terminal value, 1, but probably you want a `cmpl` or `cmpq`.  Also since 5 has been passed by value, you want to use it directly as a value, not as a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

If ret crashes, then either RSP was bad, or the return address it pops into RIP is bad.  Look at what `RSP` points at right before the `ret` executes, vs. what was there on function entry.  Your function overwrites its return address.

Since you're using a debugger already, look at where RDI is actually pointing.

It's weird that you're passing an arg on the stack in 64-bit code, and it looks like you copied the 8-byte offset from the frame pointer from 32-bit code.

In 64-bit code, every push (including the  return address pushed by `call`) is 8 bytes.  So you actually loaded your return address from `8(%rbp)`, I think.  (And then overwrite it with `mov %rax, 8(%rbp)`.)

That's why `cmpb $1, (%rdi)` doesn't fault when you deref `%rdi` by putting `()` around it, to get the memory pointed-to by RDI.  Which obviously doesn't match how you're using the bare register as the source operand for `imul`.

Your code would have faulted there if RDI held the integer you wanted it to.

---

`mov -4(%rbp), %rdi` is also wrong, loading the top half of the push and overlapping into main's saved-RBP.  If you fix the offsets in `factorial` you *could* have that function update its stack arg, but that's a weird convoluted custom calling convention.  Just have it return a value in `%rax` like a normal function.

I'm not doing your homework for you by giving you correct code; I'm intentionally just telling you where to look with a debugger for the things that are a problem.

Comment: Somewhat related, canonical Q&As: [call subroutines conditionally in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7301683) / [Does it matter where the ret instruction is called in a procedure in x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46714626)